# Unable to update Lua from 5.1.4 to 5.3 due to dependents

Tags: lua, rhel6

OS: RHEL 6

I'm trying to update Lua but it seems that there are multiple dependents on the older version of Lua which is hampering the update process. How should I proceed?

```
rpm -Uvh lua-5.3.0-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
warning: lua-5.3.0-2.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 3c3ebe43: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        liblua-5.1.so()(64bit) is needed by (installed) rpm-libs-4.8.0-55.el6.x86_64
        liblua-5.1.so()(64bit) is needed by (installed) rpm-4.8.0-55.el6.x86_64
        liblua-5.1.so()(64bit) is needed by (installed) rpm-python-4.8.0-55.el6.x86_64
        liblua-5.1.so()(64bit) is needed by (installed) rpm-build-4.8.0-55.el6.x86_64
        liblua-5.1.so()(64bit) is needed by (installed) rpm-devel-4.8.0-55.el6.x86_64
        liblua-5.1.so()(64bit) is needed by (installed) gegl-0.1.2-6.el6.x86_64
        liblua-5.1.so()(64bit) is needed by (installed) nmap-2:5.51-6.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: What means "to update Lua from 5.1 to 5.3"?  Lua 5.1 and Lua 5.3 are different incompatible languages (script for Lua 5.1 probably would not run under 5.3).  Different Lua versions should coexist on the same system without a problem.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I must add a note to your 'Script for Lua 5.1 probably would not run under 5.3' remark; When Lua 5.3 is compiled using `-DLUA_COMPAT_5_1` you will be able to run 5.1 scripts successfully, however compiled modules are a different story.

Comment: @BasGroothedde - It depends.  If your Lua 5.1 script uses `setfenv` nothing could be done in Lua 5.3 to emulate Lua 5.1 behavior.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Well, you can actually use debug.setupvalue and debug.getupvalue to do that, [see this](https://leafo.net/guides/setfenv-in-lua52-and-above.html#setting-upvalues)

Comment: @BasGroothedde - Yes, that solves the problem with pure Lua 5.1 code (if you load somehow this emulation script before each Lua 5.1 program is executed)

Comment: But if Lua 5.1 program invokes execution of some Lua 5.1 bytecode or require()-s external 5.1 module (written in C) then Lua 5.3 is indeed incompatible.

Comment: One more caveat: this emulation script is unable to `getfenv` of a function which doesn't have `_ENV` upvalue.  For example: the following script will work on Lua 5.1 but not on Lua 5.3 with `getfenv` emulator: `local globals = getfenv(function() end)` or `local globals = getfenv(1)` or `setfenv(1, new_env)`

Comment: Yes, however my original remark mentioned compiling Lua with the compat define. That means you can also write a setfenv and getfenv in C using the ldebug functions. If an env does not exist, create one and return the new env. Still fixable. Anyhow, we're straying off topic here haha